# NullPointerException when calling onClickListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm making a login system, and I don't know why this happens.
How can I fix this problem?
Here's a part of classes regarding NullPointerException.

```
    final TextView registerButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent registerIntent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });
```

And the following is a context from logcat.

```
03-22 10:37:13.066 8500-8500/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.141 3897-3897/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.gibong.capstone'!
03-22 10:37:13.166 6707-6707/? E/Launcher.Model: onPackageAdded :com.example.gibong.capstone
03-22 10:37:13.296 8526-8526/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.341 8533-8533/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.391 8539-8539/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.461 8543-8543/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.516 8561-8561/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.566 8567-8567/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.616 8572-8572/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.666 8577-8577/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.716 8581-8581/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:13.771 8587-8587/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.gibong.capstone-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
03-22 10:37:14.511 8474-8474/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.gibong.capstone, PID: 8474
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gibong.capstone/com.example.gibong.capstone.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.example.gibong.capstone.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:35)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Since I'm not fluent in English and this website, I apologize for my poor use of English and text style.

Comment: `TextView registerButton`... Strange that a button would be a `TextView`, no?

Comment: Upload you XML too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object
```

In the below line

```
final TextView registerButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
```

Are you passing the correct `id`? check that `R.id.registerButton` exists in your xml file

Comment: I found that there wasn't view id(registerButton) on xml file. I solved this problem Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Button alse extends TextView, so there is no problem :

```
final TextView registerButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
```

So, the problem is that your activity don't find a View (id=registerButton) in your xml, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.gibong.capstone.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:35)
```

Problem is in this line

```
final TextView registerButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);  // This is null
```

Make sure that you have a TextView in activity's layout that have `android:id="@+id/registerButton"` attribute

Or check it is a TextView or Button

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  the layout file contains a view that id is  "registerButton"
which declared in onCreate() 
by this code `setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);`

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException will occur when you are trying to refer an object which is not exists.

Try these ( Assumed you have declared OnclickLisener for a TextView with android:id="@+id/registerButton" inside XML )

- Define the `TextView registerButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);` under the setContentView

Comment: you can use same id until and unless they are not under the same layout. You must see the working of findViewById to know more about it.

Comment: You are Right @MohammedAtif. Thanks for your Advise :)

Answer (score -1):

You try to cast `TextView` object to `Button` object or not exists `registerButton` id in xml layout.

Comment: Button and TextView conflict will give `ClassCastException` but not `NullPointerException`.